# MS Azure : How to bind https to specific page(s) only

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on large scale enterprise application hosted in azure. Security is top priority and have been asked to secure only handful of pages.

I'm aware that there's a biding element in configuration where we can specify https/http. But, haven't found any thing where we can bind https only to number of selected pages.

Please confirm, if above is possible and if yes how would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know it can be done, not sure how though... However, I half heartedly participated in a discussion last week regarding this very issue. The people working on it declared there is no performance loss setting it up for the entire site(something about 1/100 of a second load time the first pageload then no difference). The cost of the work to set it up is higher than buying better machines to evaporate this performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you use Azure Web Roles, you own the VM. So, you can use a start-up task that configures IIS however you'd like it.

So, if you already have an on-premise solution that you like and simply want to know how to use that in Windows Azure... then the answer is - launch that process from a start-up task and it will work the same way.

Here's an article on MSDN: [Define Startup Tasks for a Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx)